# Recursively reconstruct object structure

Tags: java

I have a "HashMap> map" that represents an object tree similar to a directory tree in which parent directories can obtain further child subdirectories and so on. A value from the list can also represent a parent.

The Map contains for e.g following key/value pairs:

```
map.put(obj1,  [obj2, obj3, obj4, obj5])
map.put(obj2,  [obj6, obj7, obj8, obj9])
map.put(obj6,  [obj10, obj11, obj12, obj13])
map.put(obj10, [])
```

If I now code:

```
List children = map.get(obj1);
for(Object child : children){
   obj1.add(child);
}
```

I get the following object structure:

```
obj1--
      |
      obj2
      |
      obj3
      |
      obj3
      |
      obj5
```

And thats the point where my knowledge ends, cause I am programming not so long. I know I have code recursively to obtain the correct object structure like:

```
obj1--
      |
      obj2--
      |     |
      |     obj6--
      |     |     |
      |     obj7  obj10 
      |     |     |
      |     obj8  obj11
      |     |     |
      |     obj9  obj12
      |
      |
      obj3
      |
      obj3
      |
      obj5
```

I am struggeling with implementing a recursive working code that reconstruct the object structure in a loop.

It would be very kind if someone can bring me on the right way or can provide a little example.

Thanks in advance
John

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.LinkedHashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
public class So53579861_recursively_reconstruct_object_structure {
    static String indent() {
        String string="";
        for(int i=0;i<4*indent;i++)
            string+=" ";
        return string;
    }
    static void visit(Map<Object,List<Object>> map,Object key) {
            System.out.println(indent()+key);
            List<Object> list=map.get(key);
            ++indent;
            if(list!=null)
            for(Object object:list)
                visit(map,object);
            --indent;
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        visit(map,list.get(0));
    }
    static int indent;
    static List<Object> list=new ArrayList<>();
    static {
        for(int i=1;i<=13;i++)
            list.add(new Integer(i));
        System.out.println(list);
    }
    static Map<Object,List<Object>> map=new LinkedHashMap<>();
    static {
        List<Object> children=new ArrayList<>();
        for(int i=2;i<=5;i++)
            children.add(list.get(i-1));
        map.put(list.get(1-1),children);
        children=new ArrayList<>();
        for(int i=6;i<=9;i++)
            children.add(list.get(i-1));
        map.put(list.get(2-1),children);
        children=new ArrayList<>();
        for(int i=10;i<=13;i++)
            children.add(list.get(i-1));
        map.put(list.get(6-1),children);
        children=new ArrayList<>();
        map.put(list.get(10-1),children);
        children=new ArrayList<>();
        System.out.println(map);
    }
}
```